# DynamoDB Encountered unsupported property ProjectionType - Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm struggling to understand how to create a SecondaryGlobalIndex in DynamoDB using serverless. Here is what I got so far:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ConnectionsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: connectionId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: sessionId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: clientType
            AttributeType: S
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: connectionId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: sessionId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: clientType
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ConnectionIdIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: connectionId
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              NonKeyAttributes:
                - clientType
                - sessionId
            ProjectionType: INCLUDE
        SSESpecification:
          SSEEnabled: true
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
          AttributeName: ttl
          Enabled: true
    SessionHistoryTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: sessionId
            AttributeType: S
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: sessionId
            KeyType: HASH
        SSESpecification:
          SSEEnabled: true
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
          AttributeName: ttl
          Enabled: true
    SessionsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: sessionId
            AttributeType: S
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: sessionId
            KeyType: HASH
        SSESpecification:
          SSEEnabled: true
        TimeToLiveSpecification:
          AttributeName: ttl
          Enabled: true
```

But when I try to deploy I get this error:

```
  An error occurred: ConnectionsTable - Encountered unsupported property ProjectionType.
```

The projection type as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Projection.html) can be either `ALL | KEYS_ONLY | INCLUDE`

My question is, is there something else I'm doing wrong in the dynamoDB yaml?

Comment: `ProjectionType: INCLUDE` should be under Projection, along with `NonKeyAttributes` , but it is aligned incorrectly under `GlobalSecondaryIndexes` alongside `Projection`

Comment: also, we can't have more than one Hash Key!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProjectionType and NonKeyAttributes are properties of [Projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-table-projection.html), However ProjectionType is aligned incorrectly along side `GlobalSecondaryIndexes`

```
  GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
    - IndexName: ConnectionIdIndex
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: connectionId
          KeyType: HASH
      Projection:
        NonKeyAttributes:
          - clientType
          - sessionId
        ProjectionType: INCLUDE.  <-- aligned incorrect
```

Second concern is `KeySchema` should contain only HASH and RANGE keys, can't have multiple HASH keys.

Overall assuming that connectionId is HASH and sessionId is RANGE key.

```
  ConnectionsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: connectionId
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: sessionId
          AttributeType: S
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: connectionId
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: sessionId
          KeyType: RANGE
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: ConnectionIdIndex
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: connectionId
              KeyType: HASH
          Projection:
            NonKeyAttributes:
              - clientType
              - sessionId
            ProjectionType: INCLUDE
      SSESpecification:
        SSEEnabled: true
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: ttl
        Enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had this error Encountered unsupported property Attri buteType.
just removed space in AttributeName.